# Is singleton set of interior of a convex set an extreme point?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis, topological-vector-spaces

Let $K$ be a convex set in topological vector space and $a$ an interior point of $K$. Can it be an extreme point of $K$?

Suppose $a$ is an extreme point of $K$. Then $a=(1-t)x + ty$ for $x\neq y \in K$ and $t\in [0,1]$. Then $t=1$ or $t=0$. But if that happened every point of $K$ is an extreme point. So interior of $K$ is empty. But $a$ belongs to interior of $K$. Hence the contradiction.
So, $a$ is not an extreme point.

Is my logic correct?

Comment: Your conclusion  is correct but not your logic.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy   Actually I used definition of extreme point.

Comment: You have the definition wrongly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a valid proof. Let $a$  be an interior point of $K$ and $x$ be any non-zero vector. By the definition of  a topolgical vector space $a+\frac  1 n x$ and $a-\frac 1 n x$ tends to $a$ as $n \to \infty$. Hence, these points belong to $K$ for $n$ sufficiently large. Since $a=\frac {(a+\frac  1 n x)+(a-\frac  1 n x)} 2$ it follows that $a$ is not an  extreme point.

Comment: Yeah I got it....can I say the since $a$ is interior point of $K$ we can found a open nbd around $a$. Then boundary points of that nbd is larger than $a$ , thats contradict the maximality of $a$?